# Why ghidra skip some some address

Tags: ghidra

I have an so. Load in ghidra and set the base address to 0. I found that some address has skipped like this:

[image]

And the so is:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmea0pcirzopoll/libxxx.so?dl=0

Comment: Isn't it just how those blocks were defined in the file - check Memory map? I bet there's a gap in addresses and so does Ghidra show it in your disassembly.